# Populate Checkboxes on Edit Form

Tags: php, sql, mysql, loops

I have an edit page that gets populated when accessed. The input values work fine, but I'm having a hard time ticking the category checkboxes. I get the information from two tables. One that displays all the categories and the other one that gets the categories associated with the item.

The following code doesn't work because the second while statement finishes its loop in the first round. Is there an appropriate way to do this?

```
<?php $check_cats = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM item_categories WHERE itemid = '$itemid'") or die(mysql_error()); ?>
<?php $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY cname") or die(mysql_error()); ?>

<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) { ?>
    <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $row['cname']; ?>" name="cat[]" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" 
<?php while($check_cat_rows = mysql_fetch_array( $check_cats )) {
    if ($check_cat_rows['catid'] == $row['id']) {
      echo 'checked="yes"';
    }
  }
} ?>
```

My Two tables:

```
TABLE `item_categories`
  `id`
  `itemid`
  `catid`

TABLE `categories`
  `id`
  `cname`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your whole thing is structured incorrectly, you can't assume the two results will line up perfectly, and your loops are wrong. Try this:

```
SELECT *,
(case when id IN
(SELECT catid FROM item_categories WHERE itemid = '$itemid')
then 1 else 0 end) checked
FROM categories ORDER BY cname
```

Now you just run the one query and have a nice little `$row['checked']` to use!

```
SELECT *, 
(case when categories.id IS NOT NULL
then 1 else 0 end) checked
FROM item_categories
LEFT JOIN categories
ON (item_categories.catid = categories.id)
WHERE itemid = '$itemid'
```

Improved based on hybrid between marc B and mine... Only efficiency difference is that the query handles testing the validity of categories.id instead of the php

Comment: fixed... the inline select needed the specific column...

There may be a more efficient way of doing this, but this is the easiest to read. Marc B's query would be more prudent if you are making a very heavy weight website (Several hundred queries per second, tenthousands of rows)

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This is the limit where SQL goes right over my head :)

Comment: Actually, a compromise between Marc B's and mine could be achieved that uses case and is even more lean than both of ours... Let me see what I can throw together...

Comment: I tried his suggestion, but I couldn't figure out where the $itemid came in.

Comment: Right at the end, just add `WHERE itemid = '$itemid'`

Either way, plenty of methods now available...

Comment: The first one is the winner as I needed a query that displayed _all_ the categories and also made the check. Thanks again for the awesome help!

Answer (score 2):

Your basic structure could use improvement. Rather than two separate queries, and two nested loops, you could be using a single query which JOINS to the two tables together. Part of the joined data would be the "checked" flag, which you can check for within the loop and output the appropriate html.

```
SELECT ..., categories.id AS checked
FROM item_categories
LEFT JOIN categories
ON (item_categories.catid = categories.id)
```

and then while looping:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc()) {
      $flag = ($row['checked') ? ' checked="yes"' : ''
      ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question, but you want the check box to be checked when the page loads? In that case you have to add "checked" to the tag

```
<input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="Butter" checked>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<?php
    $query = <<<query
        SELECT
            c.id,
            c.cname,
            ifnull(ic.catid, '', 'checked="yes"') as checked
        FROM
            categories c
            LEFT JOIN item_categories ic 
                ON ic.itemid = '$itemid'
                AND ic.catid = c.id
        ORDER BY
          c.cname
query;

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
    <input type="checkbox" id="<?=$row['cname'];?>" name="cat[]" value="<?=$row['id'];?>" <?=$row['checked'];?>>
<?
}
?>
```