# How to set checkbox as checked by testing array result against another array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, checkbox

I wanted to display checkbox as checked by testing one array from query result and another one also from a query result, but I can't seem to get it...

Here's what I've come up with so far:

first query:

```
$getbficiaryres = mysqli_query($link, "
SELECT
    a.`id`,
    b.`id` as `bfryid`, b.`bficiaryname`,
    c.`notes` as `bfrynotes`
FROM 
    `activity` a, `beneficiary` b, `bficiarynotes` c, `actbficiary_link` d 
WHERE
    a.`id` = c.`activity_id` AND
    a.`id` = d.`activity_id` AND
    b.`id` = c.`beneficiary_id` AND
    b.`id` = d.`beneficiary_id` AND
    a.`id` = '".$edit."'");

$getbficiaryrow = mysqli_fetch_array($getbficiaryres);
```

first query result:

```
id  bfryid  bficiaryname bfrynotes
1   2       xxx          xxx notes
1   4       yyy          yyy notes
```

second query:

```
$bficiaryres = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT `id`, `bficiaryname` FROM `beneficiary`");
```

second query result:

```
id  bficiaryname
1   aaa
2   xxx
3   bbb
4   yyy
```

php codes:

```
$i = 0;
while($bficiaryrow = mysqli_fetch_array($bficiaryres)){
    if($bficiaryrow['id'] == $getbficiaryrow['bfryid']){    
        echo '
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label for="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="pmanfaat['.$i.']" value="'.$getbficiaryrow['bfryid'].'" checked />'.$getbficiaryrow['bfryname'].'
                    </label>
                </div><textarea name="ketpmanfaat['.$i.']" class="form-control">'.$getbficiaryrow['bfrynotes'].'</textarea>
            </div>
        </div>';

    }else{
        echo '
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label for="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="pmanfaat['.$i.']" value="'.$bficiaryrow['id'].'" />'.$bficiaryrow['bficiaryname'].'
                    </label>
                </div><textarea name="ketpmanfaat['.$i.']" class="form-control"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>';    
    }                       
    $i++;
}
```

The result that I'm expecting was to get two checkboxes xxx (id no 2)and yyy (id no 4) set as checked, but the only thing that was checked is the xxx.

How do I loop properly to get all the arrays tested?

I hope my question is clear enough.

My head' about to blow... Any help is really appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: you need two loops, one to iterate results of first query and another loops within the first loop to iterate results of second query

Comment: @mynawaz I have tried looping second query and the first query inside it, but if I do that, I only got two checkboxes... because the first query result only give out two rows. What I wanted is 4 checkboxes with two checkboxes (xxx and yyy) set as checked, how do I do this? thank you.

Comment: be sure to use two different connections for both queries, because if you use same connection for executing both queries, the inner query will reset the link identifier of outer query which will execute only one iteration

Comment: @mynawaz I have tried placing as you have suggested, but now the result shows 8 checkboxes with two checkboxes xxx and yyy set as checked, its getting closer to what I'm looking for, but now, how do I iterate only as much rows as the second query, which is only 4 checkboxes?

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this, than my comment, is to populate both arrays with you data and then follow something on the lines of code given below.

Let's suppose you build two arrays as given in example. Then iterate over the first array and search the value in second array. If a match is found, you display the checked checkbox and do nothing otherwise

```
$arr1 = array("xxx", "yyy");
$arr2 = array("aaa", "xxx", "bbb", "yyy");

foreach ($arr1 as $key => $val){
    if (in_array($val, $arr2)){
        echo("checked: ".$val."<br />");
    }
}
```

Comment: Doing the above gave me 4 checkboxes, all with the first value (aaa) and all set as checked. Where did I do wrong? T_T

Comment: make sure you've used the same control structure as my example, what you needed to do was create arr1 and arr2 from results of your queries using two separate loops and then use the foreach loop and if statement to check for matching values and display a checked check box for matching values only (nothing for non-matching values). Also note that in_array is case-sensitive i.e. xxx is not equal to Xxx and values in both arrays must be in same-case

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @mynawaz, although I'm still struggling after that, I really appreciate your trying to help. I've had learn more about arrays. Still a loong way to go for me... just keep moving forward :D

After a week or so, I finally understand, what I need is another mysql query to get the paired result using LEFT JOIN. This post helps me understand it better: [answers from one of stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229363/populate-checkboxes-on-edit-form)

thx so